# Unity3D Can you set the camera view width and height?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to fixed my camera to a square instead of a rectangle cause I'm currently working on a 2d game. I want the camera to be set to a square instead of a normal rectangle that it is set as default value. Is there any possible ways to change the values?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by changing the viewport `rect` of the `Camera`.

```
float bevel = 0F;
if (Screen.width > Screen.height)
{
  bevel = 0.5F * ((float)(Screen.width - Screen.height) / (float)Screen.width);
  cam.rect = new Rect(bevel, 0F, 1F - 2F*bevel, 1F);
}
else
{
  bevel = 0.5F * ((float)(Screen.height - Screen.width) / (float)Screen.height);
  cam.rect = new Rect(0F, bevel, 1F, 1F- 2F*bevel);
}
```